# Direct answer to an indirect question in the past

Tags: questions, reported-speech, direct-speech

Taking the indirect question:

> He asked, if she was there.

What would be the direct answer when switching from reported to direct speech in a text?

> Tim responded:
>
> "Yes, she is."

or

> "Yes, she was."

(In direct speech, it would be "Is she there?" "Yes, she is")

Comment: When being quoted, you should write exactly what the person said at that moment; thus *"Yes, she is."*

Comment: @DamkerngT. You got it. Better put it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we report people's words in direct speech (in quotes), we write exactly what the person said at that moment.

Because you want to report that Tim said *"Yes, she is"* at that time, you should write:

> Tim responded. "Yes, she is."

Comment: Thanks. I had a discussion with my English teacher about it some time ago and she said the answer and the indirect question should be in the same tens (past simple in this case). I don't remember why. It wasn't convincing, so I asked here.